# uWSGI log rotation not working

Tags: python, uwsgi, turbogears2

I am running Turbogears under uWSGI 2.0.3. All works OK except log rotation. I load my configuration from an INI file:

```
...
log-maxsize     = 104857600
daemonize       = /var/log/dumper.log
...
```

uWSGI does not rotate the log while running. If I stop/start the app then rotation gets applied. Any idea why it is not rotating the file?

Answer (score 1):

I meet the similar problem, it worked after I changed `logger=file://....`  to `logto=/.../.../`. Maybe you can try this:

```
logto=/var/log/dumper.log
```